# WAMP / PHP / LARAVEL NO RECONOCE UNA CARPETA COMPARTIDA EN RED

Tags: php, laravel, wamp

Buen día.

Tengo el siguiente problema.
El cual es que no puedo acceder a una ruta de una carpeta compartida ( Ejemplo \Pedro\carpeta\archivo.pdf ) desde mi programa de Laravel montado en un servidor WAMP.

Este servicio wamp esta montado a un servidor el cual si tiene acceso a la carpeta compartida que se menciona, ya he ingresado de manera manual a la ruta, pero una vez que se invoca la ruta en código, este no la reconoce, use la función is_dir,opendir, is_file de PHP y todas las veces estos retornan false.

Este mismo programa Laravel esta montado en otro servidor y si esta funcionando correctamente. Yo solo copie y pegue el codigo a el otro servidor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este detalle lo resolví buscando en diferentes foros de Wamp.

> El problema se debe a como se inicia WampServer, ya que este inicia con un usuario **default**.

En la [ruta](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php#79685) encontré la solución a este problema.

Lo que debe realizar es:

- Ingresar a Servicios de windows (Inicio->Servicios)
- Buscas el servicio WampApache, das clic derecho y seleccionas Propiedades
- Das clic a la pestaña Iniciar Sesión y das check a esta "Esta cuenta"
- Colocar usuario y contraseña de la computadora/servidor donde tienes montado el WAMP
- Reinicias el servicio.